# how to write project information in gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am converting a sample maven project to Gradle. In the maven project, there are tags like licenses, organization, developers. I just want to give these details in Gradle project. I have tried to add the following in `build.gradle` file,

```
licenses {
    license {
        name = 'Apache 1'
        url = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-1.0.txt'
        distribution = 'repo'
        comments = 'OSS license'
    }
}

organization {
    name = 'Sonatype'
    url = 'http://www.sonatype.com'
}
```

but it gives an error.

```
> Could not find method licenses() for arguments [build_aa7z0myalt7c30hobty4ylab$_run_closure1@227a2f2] on root project 'simple-weather' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

How to do the same, Whether I have to add some plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customizing the POM published to Maven repositories is up to the [maven-publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#sec:modifying_the_generated_pom) plugin.

Example:

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            pom {
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name = 'Apache 1'
                        url = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-1.0.txt'
                        distribution = 'repo'
                        comments = 'OSS license'
                    }
                }

                organization {
                    name = 'Sonatype'
                    url = 'http://www.sonatype.com'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```